# Python bultin method from string in list to method (<built-in function add>)

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have this code

```
def generateQuestion():
    operaton = random.choice((add, sub, mul));
    a = random.randint(0, 10);
    b = random.randint(0, 10);
    questions.append(str(a) + str(operaton) + str(b));
```

Which adds for example `6<built-in function add>4` to a list
I know I can use `questions[0]` to get it but that returns a string. How using the string can I convert the builtin method into a vaild method and have it do the math.

EDIT1: I have since modified the code to have the list contain another list [2, , 7]

```
questions.append([a, operaton, b]);
```

So if I did questions[0][1](questions[0][0], questions[0][2]) theoretically that would work?

Comment: *"Which adds for example '64' to a list"* - does it?! Why not just have a tuple `(a, op, b)` in the list?

Comment: @jonrsharpe append() takes exactly one argument (3 given)

Comment: Yes, you have to append a tuple `.append((a, op, b))` not try to append three separate things `.append(a, op, b)`.

Answer (score 2):

Just call it like so:

```
result = operation(a, b)
```

This calls `add(a, b)`, `sub(a, b)` or `mul(a, b)` depending on the function selected by `random.choice()`.

Comment: But the operation is in the list as a string.. 
    generateQuestion();
    print(questions[0]);
I want it so I can generate the question and then access it later

Answer (score 0):

With the help of the above I have figured out how to do this.

If you add a list inside a list (list.append([a, b, c])) and then do list[0][1](list[0][0], list[0][2])